# TabHost Problem on Android

Tags: android

I've created a tabs using tabhost (Let's called tab "A")

Tab "A" is the originator for activity 1

In activity 1, it is containing a button widget

Question is ....

Is it possible for A to handle more than 1 activities (switching), this is done by pressing the button appeared in activity 1 (I need the switched activity is still appeared under tab "A")

Answer (score 1):

I think you are trying to use Activity Groups:

http://united-coders.com/nico-heid/use-android-activitygroup-within-tabhost-to-show-different-activity

Answer (score 0):

don't confuse activities and views (What you see on the screen). A single activity can hide and manipulate the display all it wants. The activity is the controlling mechanism .